# Jdownloader source and strusture documentation

Tags: java, http

i'm looking for some detailed documentation of the sturcture and on the source code of jdownloader.
can someone help me to find that stuff?

Comment: jdownloader core is closed source. to compile jdownloader, you need the `Closed.jar` file. see also [jdownloader setup eclipse](https://support.jdownloader.org/Knowledgebase/Article/View/setup-ide-eclipse) ([via](https://jdownloader.org/download/index))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can say is that the source is here :[enter link description here](http://svn.jdownloader.org/projects/show/jd)

Comment: That link contains only a little part of the JDownloader source. If you download JDownloader, and extract all the .jar files, you'll have lots of .class files for which the source code is not available at http://svn.jdownloader.org/projects/show/jd .